# Store and execute functions that declared in a JSON object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to execute tasks that are declared in a Json Array. I want to reduce code as much as possible and to execute the task dynamicly. I want to try to put as much as possible in the JSON so nothing is hardcoded.

I saw some information about JSON.Net, but i am not sure that is exaclty what I am trying to do. I was wondering is someone already did something similar.

Here is an example of the JArray that i am trying to use

```
"JActions": [{
        "id": 12,
        "Dependancies": [],
        "description": "CreateTicket",
        "JFunction": "CreateTicket"
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "Dependancies": [12],
        "description": "Do the task",
        "JFunction": "ExecuteTheTask"
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "Dependancies": [12,13],
        "description": "Close the ticket with the updated information",
        "JFunction": "CloseTicket"
    }],
```

I was to deserialize the Json in a list of JActions, then do a foreach to execute the functions that are declared as JFunctions one by one. Then save the information/results back in the Object, and then re-serialize it to save it in a database

Edit: I am automating a few procedures within a team that uses a ticketing system. I am trying to find a way to call the tasks that need to be done dynamically. Currently everything is hardcoded and it is a mess to maintain, since we have ~15 automated procedure and each of those have 5-6 task/actions.

So, exaclty what i am trying to do, is declare the function that needs to be executed in the JSON, and have a loop that goes through the list and executes them in a certain order. Nothing is stopping me, I am currently researching to see how i would do it, and if someone already tried something similar.

Comment: Great - you've described a gameplan. Now which specific part of the implementation are you stuck on? What's preventing you from accomplishing your goal?

Comment: see edit, let me know if its still unclear. thanks

Comment: No, it is not not clear. You have described what you want to accomplish and a way to do it. It sounds lovely. Stack Overflow isn't here to validate your plan though. We're here to solve problems with code. So what specifically is preventing you from accomplish this? Have you tried implementing it? What kept it from working?

Comment: Not looking to validate the plan, looking to see if someone already done something similar and would guide me to a solution that would allow me to do what I am talking about. I haven't started coding yet, nor implementing anything, because i cannot find a clear way to do it, that is why i posted a question. Not trying to troubleshoot code, trying to find a solution to my problem.

Comment: You haven't actually posed a problem though: you've just stated a goal and a plan to achieve that goal. Try implementing your plan. If you get stuck on a particular part of your implementation, create a [MCVE] and then you'll probably have a valid question. As it stands now, this question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like a bad idea in general, probably an X/Y problem (You want to do X, and you think Y is the best way of doing so. Instead of asking about X, you ask about Y.)

But if I was going to implement this I would probably store the arguments and the body in your json:

```
{"function":{"arguments":"a,b","body":"return a*b;"}}
```

Now parse json and instantiate the function:

```
var f = new Function(function.arguments, function.body);
```

Answer (score -1):

Json.Net or Newtonsoft is a Library to serialize objects to JSON String or deserialize a JSON String to an object. This library alone won't be the solution.

I think you need a state machine in your code base. So first you will get a JSON, deserialize it to an object your state machine can work with and your state machine will do the rest.